# Simple C# WPF form generating a slew of seemingly nonsensical error messages

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008

The code below contains a "whole bunch" of error messages, and I can't for the life of me figure out why. I recently had to "downgrade" from VS2010 to VS2008, and have had nothing but misery since. The first few error messages are shown as comments next to where they are occurring.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO;

namespace UniClient_NextGen
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonPopMenuItemsLU_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
        { // err msg #1 = "} expected"
            public static int TOPLEVEL_ID = 0;
            public static int PARENT_ID = 1;
            public static int SELF_ID = 2;
            public static int MENU_CAPTION = 3;
            public static int MENU_NAME = 4;

            string fileName = @"C:\_UniClientNextGen\MenuItemsWithIDs.txt";
            using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(fileName)) // err msg #2 = "Invalid token 'using' in class, struct, or interface member declaration" + err msg #3 = "; expected" (at end of this line)
            {
                string _line = null;
                string[] strElements;
                do
                {
                    _line = reader.ReadLine();
                    strElements = _line.Split(",");
                    // strElements should now have five elements
                    int iTopLevelID = Convert.ToInt32(strElements[TOPLEVEL_ID]);
                    int iParentID = Convert.ToInt32(strElements[PARENT_ID]);
                    int iOwnID = Convert.ToInt32(strElements[SELF_ID]);
                    string sMenuCaption = strElements[MENU_CAPTION];
                    string sMenuName = strElements[MENU_NAME];
                    //performSQL("INSERT INTO MENU_ITEMS_LOOKUP (TopLevelMenuID, ParentMenuID, MenuItemName, MenuItemCaption) VALUES (iTopLevelID, iParentID, iOwnID, sMenuCaption, sMenuName)");
                } while (_line != null);
            }
        } // err msg #4 = "Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected" 

        private void buttonPopSorterTypesLU_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //
        }

        private void buttonPopTabsheetsLU_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //
        }

        private void buttonPopMenuItem_SorterTypeM2M_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //
        }

        private void buttonPopSorterType_TabsheetM2M_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What .NET version had the project been when you had it in VS2010, what was it before that, and what is it now?

Comment: This is a brand new project, created in VS2008, .NET 3.5 SP1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the corrected code (I have moved static member declaration in right place and corrected the _line.Splt() parameter):

```
//...
public static int TOPLEVEL_ID = 0;
public static int PARENT_ID = 1;
public static int SELF_ID = 2;
public static int MENU_CAPTION = 3;
public static int MENU_NAME = 4;

void buttonPopMenuItemsLU_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    string fileName = @"C:\_UniClientNextGen\MenuItemsWithIDs.txt";
    using(StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(fileName)) {
        string _line = null;
        string[] strElements;
        do {
            _line = reader.ReadLine();
            strElements = _line.Split(',');
            int iTopLevelID = Convert.ToInt32(strElements[TOPLEVEL_ID]);
            int iParentID = Convert.ToInt32(strElements[PARENT_ID]);
            int iOwnID = Convert.ToInt32(strElements[SELF_ID]);
            string sMenuCaption = strElements[MENU_CAPTION];
            string sMenuName = strElements[MENU_NAME];
        } while(_line != null);
    }
}
//...
```

Comment: Wholly Kau - misplaced statics and the wrong quote char causing all that mayhem!

Answer (score 3):

Why do you have `public static` declarations inside of a method?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're XAML definition or XAML namespace is not in sync with your class.  Did you recently rename a class or a namespace?

Comment: No; it's:<Window x:Class="UniClient_NextGen.Window1"